# timeGAN Model Retraining

Tags: time-series, gan

I am using timeGAN from [ydata-synthetic](https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-synthetic/blob/dev/examples/timeseries/TimeGAN_Synthetic_stock_data.ipynb) repo, and now question is about re-training the model.

Suppose we have trained a model, say `synth1`, based on a certain dataset. Now, we have new dataset which has similar data characteristics of the previous data. I am wondering if the `ydata-synthetic` package support to load the pre-trained model `synth1` (in pickle files), and then re-train to `synth2`?

I did tried loading model first and run model training like 5 epochs.
I expect the 5 epochs should not change model significantly, but it shows genertaing very different distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of the model after re-training it on a new dataset will depend on the similarity between the old and new datasets like you mentioned. If the new dataset is significantly different from the original dataset used to train the pre-trained model, the performance of the model may be affected significantly.

If the model is generating a very different distribution after re-training, there are a few things you can try to fix this issue. First, you can try adjusting the hyperparameters of the model, such as the learning rate or batch size, to see if this improves the generated distribution. Additionally, you can try training the model for more epochs than 5 to allow it to better adapt to the new dataset. If the generated distribution is still unstable, you can try using more advanced techniques such as adversarial training or adding regularization to the model to improve its stability.